# <sql:param> value for postgresql double precision column

Tags: jsp, postgresql-9.1

Can anyone please guide me how to use jstl sql param to populate a double precision column in the postgresql db? I wanna feed the data which is there in my html input tag, inside the jsp file.

Thx
Zia

Comment: [SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) Tutorial might help you.

Comment: Thx for the tutorial :-)